# Javascript callback function not being fired

Tags: javascript, callback

Apparently, the callback function is not being fired after the `firstFunction()`.
What could be going wrong?

```js
function callback () {
    console.log("this is the callback function");
}

function firstFunction () {
    console.log("this is the first function");
}

firstFunction(function () {
    callback();
});
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ibrahim said, you have to call the callback if you want it to be called :)
e.g:

```
function callback(){
    console.log("this is the callback function");

}

function firstFunction (cb){
    console.log("this is the first function");
    cb();
}


firstFunction(function () {
    callback();
});
```

or inovke the function directly in the arg:

```
firstFunction(function () {
    callback();
}());
```

EDIT:
Too late. Sorry. Anyway maybe you will find the second approach helpful.

Comment: The second approach defies the concept of callbacks.

Comment: +1 You're right. I just wanted to show how `callback` function used in this example could also be invoked. I wasn't sure of what auditore wanted to achieve. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the second function as parameter

```js
function callback() {
  console.log("this is the callback function...");
}

function firstFunction(callbackFnc) {
  console.log("this is the first function");
  callbackFnc()
}

firstFunction(callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the 'firstFunction' definition it doesn't expect a callback function.

When you invoke 'firstFunction' you are passing a function so maybe you need to change the definition a little bit. Something like...

```
function firstFunction(cb){ //now is expecting a callback function as parameter
  console.log("something");
  cb(); //calls the callback function!
}
```

Try it and check the other definitions too!

Hope it help!